# How do I raise an error with Bash?

Tags: bash, airflow

I'm trying to raise an error with Bash, in a block that's wrapped inside of a Python Airflow script.

```
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
export rundate=`TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date +%F -d "yesterday"`
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/home/ubuntu/.aws/config"
thisshouldnotrun

/home/ubuntu/bin/snowsql -f //home/ubuntu/script/dev/sql1.sql 1> /home/ubuntu/logs/"$rundate"_dev.log 2> /home/ubuntu/logs/"$rundate"_error_dev.log
```

Basically, that last line that calls the `snowsql` function will always return an exit status of 0, even when I remove the pieces of redirection. So that's why I'm redirecting to that error_dev.log file.

Basically, I want to add an `if` block and within it, manually raise an error if a file exists. I've tried adding `exit 64` but Airflow doesn't seem to like that. Is using `exit ##` the easiest to raise an error in Bash? Not sure what Airflow is even expecting to be quite honest.

Comment: Any exit status other than 1 is considered an error.

Comment: @barmar means "Any exit status other than 0 is an error"

Comment: Yeah, so `exit 64` should be throwing an error right?

Comment: Correct, `exit 64` should be treated as an error.

Comment: On UNIX-like systems, only one unsigned byte is available for an error number. So an exit value of 0 is considered success, the maximum exit value is 255.  The effect of a higher number is undefined, `exit 256` in bash will give a result of 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you `exit` with anything other than `0` it is [considered an error code in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/exit_status).

[There are several different exit codes that are returned when SnowSQL quits/exits](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#exit-codes):

> **0**:    Everything ran smoothly.
>
> **1**:    Something went wrong with the client.
>
> **2**:    Something went wrong with the command line arguments.
>
> **3**:    SnowSQL could not contact the server.
>
> **4**:    SnowSQL could not communicate properly with the server.
>
> **5**:    The exit_on_error configuration option was set and SnowSQL exited because of an error.

---

In the case of checking for a file's existence, you can use:

```
[[ -f <file> ]] && <on success> || <on failure> (exit 64, or w/e)
```

Comment: Could you please try to find a better reference than the ABS? It's to the bash world very much what W3Schools is to JavaScript -- full of bad-practice examples and outdated information, but also full of Google juice; part of why it *has* so much Google juice is that people keep linking to it. I'd suggest http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/exit_status as a better alternative on the particular subject at hand.